# Checkbox click in protractor angular

Tags: checkbox, protractor

I am trying to execute the below statements in angular:

```
const checkbox = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.1testApp-experience-checkbox'));
checkbox.click();
```

HTML:    `[class]="i+appName+'-experience-checkbox'"`

(where appName is testApp and i is 1)

> > I am getting the below error:

- Failed: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified
  (Session info: chrome=68.0.3440.106)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.41.578737 (49da6702b16031c40d63e5618de03a32ff6c197e),platform=Windows NT 6.3.9600 x86_64)

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Class name `1testApp-experience-checkbox'` seems to indicate i=1, while you are stating i=0.

Comment: I am giving that as 0 as well, even that doesn't work,
Both the ids are present on the html page so either one of them should have ideally been clicked.

Comment: And what about selecting it using its className like  `browser.driver.findElement(by.className('1testApp-experience-checkbox'))` ? Though it would surprise me if that would work, because it's just using another locator method way to select it, but you can always try.

Comment: That didn't work, but applying it to the label of the input worked.

Answer (score 0):

**Check box click using css**

```
describe("Test check box",function(){
    it("check box using css",function(){
        browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
        browser.driver.get("https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_display_checkbox_text.asp");
        const checkbox = browser.driver.findElement(by.css('.w3-check'));
        checkbox.click();
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id("text")).getText().then(function name(text) {
            console.log(text);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This works for when the input type is text, I am trying for a checkbox.

Comment: @user7108546 - Please confirm if you are using angular or non angular site and also share view source once please ....